# What's the difference between "mistrust" and "distrust"?

Tags: meaning, differences

Are **mistrust** and **distrust** synonyms?

And if so, how have two such similar words coexist for so long? Google N-grams suggests the two words have coexisted since the 1700's.

[image]

Comment: You *distrust* someone because he is bad; you *mistrust* someone because you have been too naiive. I distrust touts; people's mistrust in touts keeps them going. Juz kiddin' :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/distrust-mistrust/) has a discussion on these words:

> ***Distrust*** and ***mistrust*** are roughly the same. Both mean (1) *lack of trust* or (2) *to regard without trust*. But distrust is often based on experience or reliable information, while mistrust is often a general sense of unease toward someone or something. For example, you might distrust the advice of someone who has given you bad tips in the past, and you might mistrust advice from a stranger.
>
> [...]
>
> [However,] *mistrust* is most often used as simply a variant of *distrust*.

That sums up my thoughts pretty well.  I like the distinction, but often people don't recognize it.

Comment: I think that *mistrust* could also be used to mean "trusting someone/thing incorrectly" in the same way that *misunderstand* could mean "understanding someone/thing incorrectly".

Comment: Online Etymology Dictionary notes that ***mistrust*** came first, attested in the late 14C. ***Distrust*** (v.) appeared early 15C, and ***distrust*** (n.) early 16C. It adds: "The etymologically correct form is mistrust, in which both elements are Teutonic" [Klein]. So ***distrust*** seems to have entered the language as a hypercorrection of ***mistrust*** based on the use of the ***dis-*** prefix with other words.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I thought that was well, but I checked a dictionary and don't see any definition along the lines of 'trusting someone incorrectly'.

Answer (score 5):

Consider disuse and misuse. By extension, distrust should mean an absence of trust (cf disinterest) while mistrust should mean active suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

I think distrust has evolved to become the active-voice form of mistrust.

Consider the following sentences:

I distrust our gardener.  -vs-  I mistrust our gardener.
--the first form sounds more correct.

Hate and mistrust are the children of blindness. -vs- Hate and distrust are the children of blindness.
--again, the first form sounds more correct in the current era.

Comment: Have any source?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when we compare those words which contain the prefix mis-, and those which contain dis-, the mis- prefix more often denotes a wrongful action, as in a mistake, whereas the dis- prefix seems more to denote the intentional and not incorrect negative such as disagree or disregard. Therefore to distrust would seem to me to be the rational, intentional and calculated decision to not trust, whereas to mistrust seems to me to sound more like trusting that which should not be trusted or to trust mistakenly. I know that is not the meaning but given the way the prefixes are most often used, it would seem to me that the words would make more sense that way.

Comment: You are right in that that is not the meaning of mistrust.

Comment: This answer feels like a distake

Answer (score -5):

*Distrust* can be used as a noun and a verb. *Mistrust*, however, is purely a verb.